# Не отображаются стили css при запуске локального сервера в Intellij Idea

Tags: css, localhost, java-11

Если открыть через браузер html файл то все работает хорошо [image: введите сюда описание изображения], но если запустить локальный сервер то стили там не применяются.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ошибка из консоли [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос решен. Всем спасибо

Comment: Необходимо посмотреть в dev-консоли браузера по каким путям он не может найти файл style.css и дальше от этого отталкиваться